# Delay load of VueJS components until axios.get resolves

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I've structured a homepage based on components for each `<section>` of the page, such as:

```
 - Header component
   - _Navbar component
 - Hero component
 - Services component
 - Portfolio component
 - Footer component
```

Inner information for my page is stored into a `db.json` file that I would like to save in `public/assets/db.json` to ease the editing in future.

I'd like to use axios to get the file on run-time, then save all content in `Vue.prototype.jsonData` where all components read to structure the content in for-loops and other ways.

Tried doing the axios call in `main.js` but the page loads before axios.get is resolved, creating many errors in inner components.

**What would be the best way to achieve this?**

### GitHub

- [Code](https://github.com/PromotionEfficiency/js_vue_promoe.com.sa/blob/master/src/main.js): Current code, but no use of axios, only the import of the json which is compiled at run-time.

#### Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vueHeadful from 'vue-headful';
import App from './App.vue';
import './plugins/bootstrap-vue';
import '@babel/polyfill';
import 'mutationobserver-shim';
import './assets/css/main.scss';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';
import router from './router';
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";
import jsonData from "./assets/db.json";

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: "--------------------",
    libraries: "places" // necessary for places input
  }
});


Vue.component('vue-headful', vueHeadful);
Vue.use(VueCarousel);

Vue.prototype.jsonData = jsonData;

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: `the page loads before axios.get is resolved, creating many errors in inner components` - write the components so they handle lack of data correctly ... also ... `save all content in Vue.prototype.jsonData` is not how you want to do things in vue ... suggest you look at vuexjs if you want such central location for data .... having said all that, you still want to write your components so they don't just expect such asynchronous data to already exist

Comment: Will definitely look into `Vuexjs` and `Skeleton` to enhance the code. I'd also like to see different solutions to this challenge. thanks @JaromandaX